# Nested map and filter methods

Tags: javascript

I am trying to wrap my head around functional programming in JavaScript. My goal is to retrieve object boxarts items with `width=150` and `height=200`.

```
Console.log(arr)
```

displays

```
[ [ [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ],
[ [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ] ]
```

I am not sure why I am unable to print the 
actual values. `ConcatAll` method is used to flatten the arrays. I am working through the `reactivex.io` tutorial on Functional Programming.

```js
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
var results = [];
this.forEach(function(subArray) {
 subArray.forEach(function(item){
   results.push(item);
});
});

return results;
};

var movieLists = [
  {
   name: "Instant Queue",
   videos : [
    {
     "id": 70111470,
     "title": "Die Hard",
     "boxarts": [
      { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
      { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" }
     ],
     "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
     "rating": 4.0,
     "bookmark": []
    },
    {
     "id": 654356453,
     "title": "Bad Boys",
     "boxarts": [
      { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg" },
      { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys150.jpg" }

     ],
     "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
     "rating": 5.0,
     "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   name: "New Releases",
   videos: [
    {
     "id": 65432445,
     "title": "The Chamber",
     "boxarts": [
      { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber150.jpg" },
      { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg" }
     ],
     "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
     "rating": 4.0,
     "bookmark": []
    },
    {
     "id": 675465,
     "title": "Fracture",
     "boxarts": [
      { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
      { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg" },
      { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" }
     ],
     "url": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
     "rating": 5.0,
     "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
    }
   ]
  }
 ];

var arr = movieLists.map(function(movieList) {
 return movieList.videos.map(function(video) {
  return video.boxarts.filter(function(boxart) {
   return boxart.width === 150;
    });
   });
 });

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: *"But my code is returning an array with the words object."* What words object? The code you've actually shown works. You even said it works when using `console.log()`. So what do you mean by not being able to "print"? Please [edit] your question to explain more clearly what is going wrong, and add whatever code is associated with the incorrect behaviour. (What's `concatAll()` for? Doesn't seem to be called at all...)

Comment: your code works what do you mean by print? did you mean document.write?

Comment: console.log(arr) is displaying [ [ [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ], [ [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ] ].

Comment: But...it's *not* displaying that. When I click "Run code snippet" your code runs and the console outputs an array that may not be nested the way you want but that does include the four objects with `width:150`.

Comment: If you run the code on Chrome for Windwos in jsfiddle.net it will output the array.
https://jsfiddle.net/hk7rj2g5/ 

So I think this is something to do with the environment you are running it in.

Comment: FYI @M00 you mentioned, you want to get **boxarts items with width=150 and height=200** but in your code you wrote only `return boxart.width === 150;`

Comment: you get `[[[{"width":150,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg"}],[{"width":150,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys150.jpg"}]],[[{"width":150,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber150.jpg"}],[{"width":150,"height":200,"url":"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg"}]]]` - don't rely on console.log unless you understand what it does

Comment: @hmrc87, Yes, I think it has something to do with the environment I am running it in.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figured it out. `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));` is displaying the values in repl.it, the environment I am using.